# Taking items from a CSV file and putting the elements in a list

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a CSV File here: http://www.filedropper.com/excel which looks like this http://pastebin.com/ammzv4FK.

What I want to do is this:

Take each year with its corresponding rows and find the numbers in months and total them and assign them to variables.

So the first year, 2000, the list would look like this:

```
year2000 = ['14744', '2947', '14905', '1748',  '2859',  '11778', '1453',  '5255', '14806', '1858', '10763', '6000']
```

Then once I have that list I can convert the elements in the list from strings to integers, and sum them using the sum() command.

I can print the rows out but I'm having trouble excluding the year number and then storing the rest into variables because my list comes out as this:

```
['2000, 14744, 2947, 14905, 1748,  2859,  11778, 1453,  5255, 14806, 1858, 10763, 6000']
```

as one big string, instead of individual elements, and my list prints all the years out at once so I can't seem to figure out how to store them into variables and total them separately.

Here is my code:

```
with open("file.csv","r") as f:
    for i in range(1): 
        next(f)
    for x in f:
        x=x.split()
        print (x)
```

But when `print(x)` runs it prints it all, how can I store each year with its contents in a variable while excluding the actual year number?

I'm using Python 3, thanks.

Comment: The `csv` module is what you want. Also, you should show your current code in a question.

Comment: @syhpoon Yes, if I was able to get them into their own variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the row like that you probably aren't using a csv reader. You should use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module and store each row in a `dict`, with the year as the key. This only works if your data consists of integers.

```
data = {}

with open("data.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    reader.next() # Skip header
    for row in reader:
        row = list(map(int, row))
        data[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

To get the sum, use the built in `sum` function.

Comment: I was using the CSV module, but for your code I am getting the error 'map' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: In python 3.x, you might consider ``key, *values = list(map(int, row))`` as a nicer way of splitting the list.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: invalid literal for int() with base 10:'2011,3814,2343,6367,13244,3993,9770,5662,2278,12642,12347,14991,1910,'

Comment: Is your csv comma separated or tab separated? The one you linked is tab separated. Where did the commas come from?

Comment: Oh, my original file might be different, I had to post a shorter version but I thought I made it a CSV. My original is comma seperated.

Comment: @Goose - you might want to remove the commas at the end of each line of the original file (and also the last line that is just commas), because they are unnecessary and will result in the same invalid literal error.

Comment: @Goose: you will need to change the delimiter to match your file.

Comment: @Goose: you need to ignore the top 12 rows with that file. I'll leave that to you. You also need to ignore the last element in each row, due to the trailing `,`

Comment: I can skip the 12 lines, but I don't understand why there are commas at the last element in each row, aren't they just numbers? I'm a bit confused..When I do `print(row)` it shows it as `'1961','45119', etc,` if there were commas wouldn't it be `'1961,','45119,',etc`?

Comment: @Goose: the trailing `,` tells the csv reader that there is an empty element at the end of each row with the value `''`. This is not desired.